# Not redirecting to Cookie enable page via Python3.8+Selenium+beautifulSoap

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am working with Python + Sellenium + BeautifulSoup4 using below code but unable to open website (https://check.spamhaus.org/) and scrape over it.

My code is:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://check.spamhaus.org/"

r = requests.get(url)
htmlContent = r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlContent, 'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify)
```

Please help in informing the GAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I included some of the information from [@Nic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10446484/nic-laforge)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70575005/6045800) and used `find_element_by_id(id)` and `find_element_by_name(name)` and things started working for me. Also, in `driver.switch_to.window` function I changed the index number to 1.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.8
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import time

url = "https://check.spamhaus.org/"

options = Options()
# Disable this switch to help prevent the website to detect an automated tool (selenium)
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")

with webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/home/kkishore/Documents/doc/python-practise/updated-driver2/chromedriver',options=options) as driver:
    # This will open a new tab with the desired url
    driver.execute_script(f'''window.open("{url}","_blank");''')
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])

    # Created by Kamal
    time.sleep(5)
    # INPUT the domain name 
    driver.find_element_by_name('ip-search').send_keys('example.com')
    # Click on lookup button
    driver.find_element_by_id('ipLookup').click()
    time.sleep(10)
##    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
##    print(soup.prettify)
```

Answer (score 0):

The page does some bot detection prior allowing you to have access to the content. Because of it, the requests package won't be of any help, since `r.content` will return you the content of the loading page.

You will need to use `selenium` to achieve what you want.

```
url = "https://check.spamhaus.org/"

options = Options()
# Disable this switch to help prevent the website to detect an automated tool (selenium)
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")

with webdriver.Chrome(options=options) as driver:
    # This will open a new tab with the desired url
    driver.execute_script(f'''window.open("{url}","_blank");''')
    # Switch to the active window
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])

    # Waiting until the page is loaded (Validating the ipLookup button)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'ipLookup')))

    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    print(soup.prettify)
```

You will also need to add the following imports:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

I have not used `driver.get(url)` but instead `window.open()` this will actually open a new tab with the desired URL. I cannot 100% explain why, but using `driver.get()`, the page was still not passing the loading page.

As for your comment question here's how you may perform a search

```
search_button = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'ipLookup')))

search_text_field = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[name="ip-search"]')
search_text_field.send_keys('1.1.1.1')
search_button.click()
```

Comment: Thanks @Nic for prompt reply. But through your code I am not able to perform further actions like search for IP or domain. Your assistance will be appreciated! I tried below code ' driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/main/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/form/div/input").click()
 driver.find_element_by_id("ipLookup").send_keys('design.com')` and through wait variable too = `wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'ipLookup'))).send_keys('xyz.com')` but no luck

Comment: ipLookup is the search button not the input field. Try: `driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[name]="ip-search"')`

Comment: Its not working , RESULT: selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified

Comment: Right.. the selector was wrong. I have updated the answer with a search example. Also note this added line `driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])`. If this answer works, please don't forget to accepted it.